# How to install php extension on bluemix?

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, php-extension

I need to install pecl_http extension on bluemix, which pecl_http itself require raphf.so and propro.so. I already downloaded .zip file of it

if the solution is building a buildpack please provide clear answer or provide good source. I tried to open https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack and got no clear guide to add extension.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library isn't available on php buildpack.
You should switch to proper http methods for php, or better use curl extension, available and also more customisable than pecl_http

Comment: I already using curl, but in my case I can subtitute it with another package but if I really need some package how to achieve this? like mongodb module etc.

Comment: The buildpacks are usually available on github so are opensource, you could clone one and modify to add one or specific modules or extension without any problem and then push on Bluemix using your custom buildpack. Or at least look over Internet for a buildpack providing it (for example take a look on the zend php buildpack)

Comment: thanks, now out of topic, do you use bluemix too? if yes do you have issue with response time? I mean not the ping but compute time of bluemix

Comment: Yes I use Bluemix and I find it responsive in computing time. Are you having latency in the http requests sent from Bluemix to outside?

Comment: yes I'm having latency from bluemix, when I requested my API using postman extension (chrome) the time not consistent on the fastest time. I mean the fastest time is around 200ms but sometimes I request again it wait until 2 seconds, and I'm sure it's not my internet lagging. I'm in Indonesia.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps -

"The buildpack is designed with an extension mechanism, allowing application developers to add behavior to the buildpack without modifying the buildpack code.

When an application is pushed, the buildpack runs any extensions found in the .extensions directory of your application."

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/php/gsg-php-config.html

Comment: thanks, already found the link and if you read the section about installing extension its a very lovely 2 lines explanation that doesn't help at all.